# OpenCV imgproc not found

Tags: 20.04, compiling, c++, arm, opencv

i am trying to compile a OpenCV Application for an ARMs target.

I crosscompiled all the libraries but when i try to compile my code:

```
#include<opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/objdetect.hpp>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    VideoCapture video(0);
    CascadeClassifier facedetect;
    Mat img;
    facedetect.load("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
    
    while (true) {
        video.read(img);

        vector<Rect> faces;

        facedetect.detectMultiScale(img, faces, 1.3, 5);

        cout << faces.size() << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++) {
            rectangle(img, faces[i].tl(), faces[i].br(), Scalar(50, 50, 255), 3);
            rectangle(img, Point(0,0), Point(250,70), Scalar(50, 50, 255), FILLED);
            putText(img, to_string(faces.size())+" Face Found", Point(10, 40), FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 1, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 1);
        }

        
        imshow("Frame", img);
        waitKey(1);
        

    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

with this command →

> /home/apc1wi/Documents/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-g++ test.cpp -o test_EVAL -I /usr/local/include/opencv4 -L/home/apc1wi/Documents/opencv_crosscompile/opencv-4.x/build/lib/ -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc.so

i get this error

> cannot find -lopencv_imgproc.so collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Note: The library is there, as well as the highui and the core which it seems to find. Any suggestions ?

Comment: `-lopencv_imgproc.so` should probably be just `-lopencv_imgproc` in your command